# Criar função strstr / Retorno ponteiro em C

Tags: c

Estou tentando refazer a função strstr (procura um valor passado por parâmetro num texto, se encontrar mostra o resto) por conta.

Esse é meu código atual, ele já chegou a funcionar mas dei algum miss click e parou de funcionar por alguma razão.

Creio que esteja fazendo alguma declaração errada nos ponteiros/array

segue o código

```
/* strstr.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *ft_strstr(char *str, char *to_find)
{   
    int index;
    int aux2;
    char *aux3;

    index = 0;
    aux2 = 0;
    aux3 = 0;



    while (str[index] != '\0')
    {

           if (to_find[aux2] == str[index]) {
                aux3[aux2] = str[index];
                  aux2++;
                  index++;

                if (to_find[aux2] == '\0')
                {
                    while (str[index] != '\0')
                    {
                        aux3[aux2] = str[index];
                        aux2++;
                        index++;

                        if (str[index] == '\0')
                        {
                         return aux3;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        index++;
        }

    return (0);
}

int main(void)
{
    /* char *psResultado;
    char sFrase[] = "isto e um teste";

    printf("\nEndereço Inicial = %s", sFrase );

     A função retornará o endereço correspondente à localização do "to" 
    psResultado = strstr(sFrase, "vasc");

    printf("\nEndereço inicial para a pesquisa = %s\n", psResultado );
    printf("\nEndereço inicial para a pesquisa = %s\n", psResultado );
    */

    printf("%s",ft_strstr("Testando","st"));

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro temos isso:

```
    aux2 = 0;
    aux3 = 0;
```

Depois temos isso:

```
                aux3[aux2] = str[index];
```

Ou seja, você está tentando escrever algo em um ponteiro nulo.

Para implementar a `strstr` adequadamente, você não deveria nem criar novas strings e nem escrever nada em qualquer uma das strings. Além disso, o seu programa parece ser muito mais complicado do que o necessário.

A solução adequada seria fazer isso:

- Percorrer todas as posições `i` da `str` até ela acabar (retornando-se `NULL`) ou até que o `to_find` seja encontrado.
- Para cada posição `i` em `str`, percorrer as posições `j` de `to_find` junto com as posições `i + j` de `str` até que um caractere diferente seja encontrado ou até o `to_find` terminar (e neste caso retorna-se o endereço da `i`). Deve-se tomar cuidado para não se ultrapassar o final de nenhuma das strings.

Eis o código que faz isso:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char *ft_strstr(const char *str, const char *to_find) {
    if (str[0] == 0 && to_find[0] == 0) return str;
    for (int i = 0; str[i]; i++) {
        int j;
        for (j = 0; to_find[j] && str[i + j] && to_find[j] == str[i + j]; j++);
        if (to_find[j] == 0) return &(str[i]);
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main(void) {
    printf("1: %s\n", ft_strstr("Testando", "st"));
    printf("2: %s\n", ft_strstr("O rato roeu a roupa do rei de Roma", "ro"));
    printf("3: %s\n", ft_strstr("Nao vai achar", "vai nada"));
    printf("4: %s\n", ft_strstr("Vai achar no fim", "fim"));
    printf("5: %s\n", ft_strstr("Logo no inicio vai ser encontrado", "Logo no inicio"));
    printf("6: %s\n", ft_strstr("Nao vai procurar nada", ""));
    printf("7: %s\n", ft_strstr("", "Vai procurar em lugar nenhum"));
    printf("8: %s\n", ft_strstr("", ""));
    return 0;
}
```

Todos os testes da função `main` dão o resultado esperado:

```
1: stando
2: roeu a roupa do rei de Roma
3: (null)
4: fim
5: Logo no inicio vai ser encontrado
6: Nao vai procurar nada
7: (null)
8:
```

O `if` do começo da função `ft_strstr` serve para lidar com o caso 8 acima, que é um caso especial. O resto da função é a implementação do algoritmo que descrevi acima.

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/vTHPMs)