# Problema com malloc em C ao criar função de concatenação de strings

Tags: c, alocação

```
char *ft_concat_params(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int index;
    int aux2;
    char **newString = argv;

    aux2 = 0;


    while (argv[aux2] != '\0')
    {
    index = ft_strlen(argv[aux2]);
    newString[aux2] = (char *) malloc (index * sizeof(char *));
    ft_strcpy(newString[aux2],newString[aux2]);
    aux2++;
    }
```

Tenho esse código. Quando dou o `malloc`, a função fica vazia. Alguma solução?

Comment: Como assim "a função fica vazia"? É que definição você deu à `ft_strcpy`? E por que você copia do mesmo objeto para ele mesmo em `ft_strcpy`? Ambos os parâmetros são `newString[aux2]`, portanto são idênticos.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Pergunta relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/251166/132

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro conte quanta memória você vai precisar. Depois aloque a memória e só depois comece a concatenar. Para não termos que usar `ft_strlen` duas vezes em cada string, pode-se usar uma cache.

Além disso, no `malloc` você usou `sizeof(char *)` ao invés de `sizeof(char)`, e portanto acabaria alocando muito mais memória que o necessário. Na verdade, como `sizeof(char)` é 1 sempre, você não precisa usá-lo neste caso.

Também, o seu `ft_strcpy(newString[aux2],newString[aux2]);` é muito estranho. Colocar o conteúdo de uma string nela mesma não é algo que faça lá muito sentido.

E você está alocando a string dentro do `while` (e nada de liberar ela). Como você só quer produzir uma única string no final, alocar dentro do `while` não vai funcionar.

Antes de tudo, precisamos de `#include <stdlib.h>` e da implementação de `ft_strcpy` e `ft_strlen`:

```
char *ft_strcpy(char *dst, const char *src) {
    int i = -1;
    do {
        i++;
        dst[i] = src[i];
    } while (src[i]);
    return dst;
}

int ft_strlen(const char *src) {
    int i = 0;
    while (src[i]) i++;
    return i;
}
```

Eis o seu código revisado:

```
char *ft_concat_params(int argc, char **argv) {

    // Cache com os tamanhos das strings.
    int *cache = (int *) malloc(argc * sizeof(int));

    // Conta o tamanho das strings.
    int count = 1; // 1 = espaço do terminador nulo.
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        cache[i] = ft_strlen(argv[i]);
        count += cache[i];
    }

    // Cria a nova string que será retornada.
    char *newString = (char *) malloc(count);

    // Copia as strings para o newString.
    // Usa aux para percorrer o espaço de memória de newString.
    char *aux = newString;
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        ft_strcpy(aux, argv[i]);
        aux = &(aux[cache[i]]);
    }

    // Adiciona o terminador nulo.
    aux[0] = 0;

    // Não precisamos mais da cache.
    free(cache);

    // Terminamos.
    return newString;
}
```

Para testar esse código (junto com o `#include <stdio.h>`), usamos isso:

```
int main(void) {
    const char *strings1[] = {"banana", "pera", "uva"};
    char *a = ft_concat_params(3, strings1);
    printf("[%s] - %d\n", a, ft_strlen(a));
    free(a);

    const char *strings2[] = {"", "teste", "", "mais", "", "perigoso", ""};
    char *b = ft_concat_params(7, strings2);
    printf(["%s] - %d\n", b, ft_strlen(b));
    free(b);

    const char *strings3[] = {"", "", ""};
    char *c = ft_concat_params(3, strings3);
    printf("[%s] - %d\n", c, ft_strlen(c));
    free(c);

    const char *strings4[] = {};
    char *d = ft_concat_params(0, strings4);
    printf("[%s] - %d\n", d, ft_strlen(d));
    free(d);

    return 0;
}
```

Eis a saída:

```
[bananaperauva] - 13
[testemaisperigoso] - 17
[] - 0
[] - 0
```

Esses dois últimos eram para ser vazios, mesmo. São testes de casos especiais.

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/bE2aZT)

É possível implementar-se isso sem usar a cache e nem usar `ft_strlen` mais de uma vez, se não usarmos o `ft_strcpy` trocando-se o pedaço que copia as strings para isso:

```
    // Copia as strings para o newString.
    // Usa aux para percorrer o espaço de memória de newString.
    char *aux = newString;
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; argv[i][j]; j++, aux++) {
            aux[0] = argv[i][j];
        }
    }
```

A saída produzida é a mesma.

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/Zq79Vk)

Para saber-se qual das abordagens teria melhor desempenho, seria necessário fazer-se testes bem complexos, e isso depende também de como a `ft_strcpy` é implementada. Outras abordagens bem diferentes certamente também são possíveis.